SQL - Update one column with 2 different values according to a CTE
I have a table people:



person_id
is_student




001
null


002
null


003
null


004
null


005
null



And a CTE student_population which contains all id for people who are students:



student_id




003


004


005



I want to update is_student in people with T/F values. This is the result i want:



person_id
is_student




001
F


002
F


003
T


004
T


005
T



The code i'm using is:
with student_population as (
    select ... from...
)
update 
    people p
set 
    is_student = case
        when p.person_id = stu.student_id then 'T'
        else 'F'
    end
from 
    student_population stu

I only got one 'T' in people after running this code, for the first id in is_student. All other values are all 'F's. this is the wrong result i'm getting:



person_id
is_student




001
F


002
F


003
T


004
F


005
F



How should I fix this?

Are you sure you're using MySQL? You can't have a FROM clause in UPDATE.

Is FROM is_student supposed to be FROM student_population?

If you're actually using SQL-Server, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server/2334741#2334741

I'm actually using postgres sql. Sorry for the confusion. And yes, FROM is_student is supposed to be FROM student_population. I've edited the question and tag. Thanks for pointing this out!

Your Postgres update join is missing a WHERE clause which connects the two tables involved.  Try this version:
update people p
set is_student = case when stu.student_id is not null then 'T' else 'F' end
from student_population stu
where p.person_id = stu.student_id;

But this might only update the true matches of students which appear in the CTE.  To update the false records as well, we can use this version:
update people p
set is_student = (
    select case
        when exists (
            select 1 from student_population stu where p.person_id = stu.student_id
    )   then 'T' else 'F' end
);

